# Could not get xml data in the response using fetch in react

Tags: xml, reactjs, rest

I'm using Great Schools Api :

```
fetch("https://api.greatschools.org/search/schools?key=***********&state=CA&q=cupertino&levelCode=elementary-schools&limit=1",{ 
    method: 'GET',
    Accept:'application/xml',
    headers : new Headers ({
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',  
    }),
    mode:'no-cors'
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response, 'data')
    })
```

console for response is :

```
Response
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {  }
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
```

But in Browser Network console I'm geting correct XMl response.

How to get correct response.

Answer (score 1):

You are logging the response object.

You need to access the response body.

You can do this by returning `response.text()`

From the [fetch docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

> Body.text() 
>   Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It
>   returns a promise that resolves with a USVString (text).

```
fetch("https://api.greatschools.org/search/schools?key=***********&state=CA&q=cupertino&levelCode=elementary-schools&limit=1",{ 
    method: 'GET',
    headers : new Headers ({
      'Accept:'application/xml',
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',  
    }),
    mode:'no-cors'
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.text()
    })
    .then(xml => {
      console.log("xml", xml)
    })
```

Comment: Still no use. Just string 'xml' is getting printed in the console.

Comment: Can you make an API request in postman and show us the result?

Comment: API : https://api.greatschools.org/search/schools?key=************&state=CA&q=cupertino&levelCode=elementary-schools&limit=3  ,  Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<schools>
    <school>
        <gsId>9094</gsId>
        <name>St. Joseph of Cupertino Elementary School</name>
        <type>private</type>
        
        <lat>37.3243</lat>
        <lon>-122.032</lon>
        
        
    </school>
</schools>

Comment: Have updated my post. You need to move the `accept` property to the headers object.

Comment: No Result, only "xml" is getting printed in the console

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with your request as the response object is returning `ok: false`. What is different between your postman request and the fetch request?

Comment: Actually there is no change except for the headers we are adding.

Comment: Can you try removing the headers so your request is exactly like the postman request and see if that works? Basically the API is not returning a failed response for some reason

Comment: No progress still same empty response

Answer (score 1):

When the Response's type is opaque as shared by you, it means that the request  is still blocked by cors. The browser's network tab shows you the request's response but the fetch's callback would only show you opaque response. Additionally, response.ok would be true if the fetch is actually successful and the response is ready to be consumed in the callback